# How do I add a border to a flutter button?

Tags: button, dart, icons, flutter, border

I've just recently gotten into flutter and am loving it so far but I've gotten stuck on some UI changes. Any help is appreciated!

My goal is to get a circular button that has an icon with a blue background but then have a border around the outside that is a darker blue. There are pictures attached.

My approach was:

1. Get a circular blue button.
2. Put an icon in that button.
3. Add a border.

I got stuck on step 3 because I do not know how to add a border, or if it is even possible given the way I approached the problem. The specific colors do not matter to me at the moment, I will change the theme later.

This is what I currently have code wise:

```
  var messageBtn = new Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: new RawMaterialButton(
        onPressed: _messages,
        child: new Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: new Icon(
            Icons.message,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        shape: new CircleBorder(),
        fillColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      ),
    ),
    new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: new Text(
          'Send Messages',
          style: new TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
          ),
        )),
  ],
);
```

It produces this: [image: see screenshot]

I want this:[image: see second screenshot]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Hi Kathleen and welcome!

You can achieve what you want by diving a little deeper into the widgets that make up `MaterialButton`.

First you need the [Ink](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Ink-class.html) widget. This offers more flexible styling using a [BoxDecoration](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html).

`Ink` can then contain an [InkWell](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) widget which recognises `onTap` and draws the splash effect. By default, the splash continues to the edges of the containing box, but you can make it circular by giving `InkWell` a really big `borderRadius`.

Here's an example of the button you're after:

```
Material(
  type: MaterialType.transparency, //Makes it usable on any background color, thanks @IanSmith
  child: Ink(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.indigoAccent, width: 4.0),
      color: Colors.indigo[900],
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
    ),
    child: InkWell(
      //This keeps the splash effect within the circle
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1000.0), //Something large to ensure a circle
      onTap: _messages,
      child: Padding(
        padding:EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.message,
          size: 30.0,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
),
```

And here's the result:

[image: screenshot of Flutter app with custom styled button]

Comment: Hmm, did an update break this? This now has a whitebox as the background due to the BoxDecoration shape. Maybe it was never noticed..

Comment: @IanSmith, it's still working for me on the latest Flutter stable (1.17). Happy to take a look at your code.

Comment: @Xander here's an example app showing the issue: https://pastebin.com/raw/tTCVzRmP

Comment: @IanSmith Thanks, I see what you mean. We should probably be using `Material(type: MaterialType.transparency)`. I'll update the answer 

Answer (score 28):

Just wrap an `IconButton` into a `Container` and set its `decoration` as following:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 4),
    color: Colors.yellow,
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
  ),
  child: IconButton(
    iconSize: 56,
    icon: Icon(Icons.check),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
),
```

and you will get the same result in less code.

[image: Flutter circular button with a border]

Answer (score 18):

Can Using FloatingActionButton with Border :

```
   FloatingActionButton(
                              mini: false,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900,
                              splashColor: Colors.black,
                              onPressed: () {
                                logOutDialog(context);
                              },
                              hoverElevation: 1.5,
                              shape: StadiumBorder(
                                  side: BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.blue, width: 4)),
                              elevation: 1.5,
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.logout,
                                color: _foregroundColor,
                              ),
                            )
```

Comment: Wow! Your answer was really useful for doing one of those BottomNavigationBar effects where the FAB is shaping the navbar!

Comment: I'm happy @miguel-jara , please (if possible) record a gif from your user interface and edit my answer!

Answer (score 3):

In Flutter 2 there is `TextButton`:

```
TextButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
   side: RedSelectedBorderSide(),
  ),
  child: Text(
    "Button"
  ),
  onPressed: (){}
);
```

Where `RedSelectedBorderSide()` is:

```
class RedSelectedBorderSide extends MaterialStateBorderSide {
  @override
  BorderSide resolve(Set<MaterialState> states) {
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
      return BorderSide(
        width: 2,
        color: Colors.red,
      ); // 
    }
    return null;// Defer to default value on the theme or widget.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For `TextButton`

inside `style` use `side` with `MaterialStateProperty` with `BorderSide`.

```flutter
TextButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
   side: MaterialStateProperty.all(
     BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black),
   ),
  ),
  child: Text(
    "My Button"
  ),
  onPressed: (){}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here to find out how to add border to "CupertinoButton". I'll post my finding here. Hope it will help to someone.

Result :

[image]

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

...

CupertinoButton(
    minSize: 20,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0), // remove button padding
    color: CupertinoColors.white.withOpacity(0),  // use this to make default color to transparent
    child: Container(   // wrap the text/widget using container
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10), // add padding
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 211, 15, 69),
            width: 1,
          ),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),  // radius as you wish
        ),
      child: Wrap(
         children: const [
           Icon(CupertinoIcons.videocam_circle_fill, color: CupertinoColors.systemPink,),
           Text(" Upload video", style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.systemPink),)
         ],
       ),
    ),
    onPressed: () {
      // on press action
    },
),
```