# How to set the background color of a Flutter OutlineButton?

Tags: flutter

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("..."),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: OutlineButton(
          onPressed: () { },
          color: Colors.orange,
          highlightColor: Colors.pink,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: Text("A"),
          ),
          shape: CircleBorder(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

The above code gives a transparent button. How can I get an orange OutlineButton?

Comment: Please Visit following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52303225/4843725) I think it is related to your problem...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To modify the backgroundColor of a [OutlineButton](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/OutlineButton-class.html) you can use a [DecoratedBox](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/DecoratedBox-class.html) and a [Theme](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Theme-class.html) widget. At the end of this answer you'll find a quick example.

Anyway I'd still **recommend** simply using the [FlatButton](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html) with its `color` attribute instead.

Wrap your `OutlinedButton` inside a `DecoratedBox`. Set the `shape` of your `DecoratedBox` to the same shape your `OutlinedButton`. Now you can use the `color` attribute of your `DecoratedBox` to change the color. The result will still have a small padding around the `OutlinedButton`. To remove this you can wrap the `DecoratedBox` inside a `Theme` in which you adjust the `ButtonTheme`. Inside the `ButtonTheme` you want to set `materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap`.

The padding is added inside Flutter, to increase the tap area around the button to a minimum size of 48x48 [(source)](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2994d3562a0abb4a4db0fefdab27907e934cd161/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/button.dart#L210). Setting `materialTapTargetSize` to `MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap` removes this minimum size.

---

`FlatButton` example:

[image: Demo]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: FlatButton(
            color: Colors.pinkAccent,
            shape: CircleBorder(),
            onPressed: () => {},
            child: Text('A'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

`OutlinedButton` example:

[image: Demo]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyButton(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration:
          ShapeDecoration(shape: CircleBorder(), color: Colors.pinkAccent),
      child: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            buttonTheme: ButtonTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap)),
        child: OutlineButton(
          shape: CircleBorder(),
          child: Text('A'),
          onPressed: () => {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I added a `FlatButton` example, which I'd recommend because it is way more simple.

Comment: Very helpful. I needed a square so used ContinuousRectangleBorder() instead of CircleBorder()

Comment: So OutlineButton is being depreciated for OutlinedButton and the schema is different.

Answer (score 27):

`OutlineButton` has been deprecated and has been replaced with `OutlinedButton`. (Notice the "d".)

`OutlinedButton`'s [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/OutlinedButton-class.html) helped me understand how to use it. Here's an example with these states: Disabled (Grey) --> Normal (Blue) --> Pressed (Red)

[image: Outlined-Button-Disabled-Normal-Pressed]

```
   return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 48,
      child: OutlinedButton(
        child: Text(
          "This is an Outline\"d\"Button. (Not OutlineButton)",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        onPressed: () => print("Tapped"),
        //onPressed: null, //Uncomment this statement to check disabled state.
        style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>((states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
              return Colors.grey[100];
            }
            return Colors.blue;
          }),
          overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>((states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
              return Colors.red;
            }
            return Colors.transparent;
          }),
          side: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
            Color _borderColor;

            if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
              _borderColor = Colors.greenAccent;
            } else if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
              _borderColor = Colors.yellow;
            } else {
              _borderColor = Colors.pinkAccent;
            }

            return BorderSide(color: _borderColor, width: 5);
          }),
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<OutlinedBorder>((_) {
            return RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16));
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Flutter replaced the former 3 button types (`FlatButton`, `RaisedButton` and `OutlineButton`) with new buttons types (`TextButton`, `ElevatedButton` and `OutlinedButton`) to remain in sync with Material design and also because using `MaterialStateProperty` provides the ultimate flexibility to achieve whatever state-specific-UI one needs. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10Fbn59hiHkppqJ6y_1Rjwl7klN-OvJXQU3SFEqicpME/view).

Answer (score 6):

It is pretty much easy, just use

```
backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.colorname),
```

Comment: Hi there
I see you are new here
Please be more specific when answering questions and add a bit more explanation on how to solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

If you need to Change Colour of Outline Border

```
 OutlineButton(
borderSide: BorderSide(color: kPrimaryColor, width: 1),)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's way that you can check the background color of the button.
Remove hightlightColor, and try give some value to highlightElevation property of OutlineButton, then press it, you could see initially it loads orange color.

Comment: I think OutlineButton seems have its original behavior and hard to configure it. Essentially OutlineButton extends MaterialButton, so why don't you try out MaterialButton instead?