# Flutter :- Create circular border around icons

Tags: flutter, icons, flutter-layout

I want to create circular borders around the icons as shown in the image.
[image: layout]

```
Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                color: Colors.white,
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 2
                )
              ),
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward,color: Colors.white,),
            )
```

I don't need cuts in the circular borders as they are shown in the image but the complete circular border, I have also tried this code =>[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52302625/how-do-i-add-a-border-to-a-flutter-button)

Comment: post your code then

Comment: @pskink sry for not posting code, but I have edited the question and provide some more info.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I am doing some mistakes in my above code. but I have figured out and here is the new code.

```
Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                      border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.white)),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.cancel,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                )),
```

Also if you want to make complete Widget clickable then you can use it like this.

```
GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              //Navigator.of(context).pop();

            },
            child: new Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                      border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.white)),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.cancel,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                )),
          ),
```

Answer (score 25):

```
Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.white)
            ),
            child: Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.white,),
          )
```

or you can use Material if you're going to need some fancy effects:

```
Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            shape: CircleBorder(
              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)
            ),
            child: Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.white,),
          )
```

Comment: This is a much better answers

Answer (score 5):

**Updated: OutlinedButton (instead of deprecated OutlineButton)**

```
OutlinedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    style: ButtonStyle(
      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
      )),
    ),
    child: Icon(Icons.print, color: Colors.green),
  )
```

**Original response:**

I think that the easiest way is to use an `OutlineButton`:

```
OutlineButton(
  onPressed: () { },
  shape: CircleBorder(),
  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
  child: Icon(Icons.print, color: Colors.green),
)
```

Comment: This was correct. Now it is deprecated in favor of `OutlinedButton`

Answer (score 0):

You can also go with **`FloatingActionButton`**.